# How to set an element unclickable in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm trying to make a watermark for a TextBox in WPF.
For that purpose I have a styled label over the TextBox.

```
<Grid>

    <TextBox   Height="15" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          DataContext="{Binding FilterDetailsViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
          Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay }"    
          TextChanged="SearchPatientByName"
          Padding="0 0 0 3"
          />
    <Label Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="WaterMarkLabel" Content="Search" VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Visibility="Visible" Foreground="Gray" FontFamily="Arial">
    </Label>  
                              
</Grid>
```

When the text of the TextBox is empty the Label is visible, otherwise not.

the problem is when the label gets the focus, I'm unable to change the text in the TextBox.

I need to find a way to make this Label unclickable.

Comment: I'm no WPF expert but is the `IsHitTestVisible` property what you need?

Comment: Thanks, That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
       <Grid Height="20">
        <TextBox Background="{x:Null}" Panel.ZIndex="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
        TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" >
        </TextBox>
        <StackPanel  Background="#FFF3F3F3">
            <Label x:Name="watermarklabel" Content="search" />
        </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
```

for Textbox textchanged(Label name is watermarklabel):

```
 TextBox ME = sender as TextBox;
        if (ME.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            watermarklabel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            watermarklabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```